# Где ошибка в операторе for?

Tags: c++, циклы, объявление, for

Здравствуйте, компилятор (Visual Studio) жалуется на цикл `for` (а именно как я его объявил, с несколькими переменными). В чём ошибка? Почитал на сайтах, так же можно делать.

```
for (seqList* cur = sequence, int j = 0; j < len; cur = cur->next, j++) {
    this->addElem(cur->elem->value);
}
```

Переменная `len` объявлена, если что.

Comment: так нельзя делать, можно только объявлять несколько переменные одного типа.

Comment: В языке С++ нет и никогда не было синтаксиса объявления через запятую `seqList* cur = sequence, int j = 0`. Откуда вы такое взяли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете давать несколько объявлений в заголовке

```
seqList* cur = sequence, int j = 0;
```

Вернее, несколько объявлений разных типов...

Но можно сыграть с помощью структуры:

```
struct Intern
{
    seqList * cur;
    int j;
};

for(Intern x = { sequence, 0 }; x.j < len; x.cur = x.cur->next, x.j++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Или с помощью кортежа:

```
for(tuple<seqList*,int> x = { sequence, 0 };
    get<1>(x) < len;
    get<0>(x) = get<0>(x)->next, get<1>(x)++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Или даже так (С++17):

```
for(auto [cur,j] = make_tuple(sequence,0);
    j < len;
    cur = cur->next, j++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, через 12 мин отмечу правильным. Не ясно только по каким причинам этого нельзя делать..

Comment: @ReCursia: Я бы сказал, что это скорее у вас надо спрашивать, почему это вдруг должно быть можно делать.

Comment: Интуитивно показалось, что можно :)

Comment: Посмотрите последний вариант в ответе - практически можно :)